# Platform independant thread pool v4

Tags: c++, multithreading, reinventing-the-wheel, c++14

## This is a continuation of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54986/platform-independant-thread-pool-v3) question.

Following the previous advise, the thread pool now can handle almost all types of input, except for one key form, where the function/functor requires one of its arguments to be `std::move`'d as shown below.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "threadpool.hpp"

threadpool pool;

int main()
{
    auto ptr1 = std::make_unique<unsigned>();
    *ptr1 = 10;

    auto lambda1 = [](std::unique_ptr<unsigned> ptr) { return *ptr; };

    auto ptr2 = std::make_unique<unsigned>();
    *ptr2 = 10;

    auto lambda2 = [ptr = std::move(ptr2)]() { return *ptr; };

    //  fails with below compile error
    auto future1 = pool.enqueue_task(lambda1, std::move(ptr1));
    std::cout << future1.get() << std::endl;

    //  compiles fine
    auto future2 = pool.enqueue_task(std::move(lambda2));
    std::cout << future2.get() << std::endl;
}
```

You get this error message:

```
./task_package.hpp:36:27: error: no matching function for call to object of type
      'std::__1::__bind<<lambda at main.cpp:12:20> &,
      std::__1::unique_ptr<unsigned int, std::__1::default_delete<unsigned int>
      > >'
        promise.set_value(func());
                          ^~~~
```

As usual, here is the bulk of the code, any more improvements/comments, especially with respect to optimisations, are more than welcome!

#### threadpool.hpp

```
#ifndef THREADPOOL_HPP
#define THREADPOOL_HPP

#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

#include "task_package.hpp"

//#define USE_YIELD

class threadpool
{
public:
    //  constructor
    //
    //  calls threadpool(size_t concurrency) with:
    //
    //  concurrency - std::thread::hardware_concurrency()
    threadpool();
    //  constructor
    //
    //  calls threadpool(size_t concurrency, size_t queue_size) with:
    //
    //  concurrency - concurrency
    //  queue_size  - 128, arbitary value, should be sufficient for most
    //                use cases.
    threadpool(size_t concurrency);
    //  constructor
    //
    //  creates a threadpool with a specific number of threads and
    //  a maximum number of queued tasks.
    //
    //  Argument
    //    concurrency - the guaranteed number of threads used in the
    //                  threadpool, ie. maximum number of tasks worked
    //                  on concurrently.
    //    queue_size  - the maximum number of tasks that can be queued
    //                  for completion, currently running tasks do not
    //                  count towards this total.
    threadpool(size_t concurrency, size_t queue_size);

    //  destructor
    //
    //  Will complete any currently running task as normal, then
    //  signal to any other tasks that they were not able to run
    //  through a std::runtime_error exception
    ~threadpool();

    threadpool(const threadpool &)             = delete;
    threadpool(threadpool &&)                  = delete;

    threadpool & operator=(const threadpool &) = delete;
    threadpool & operator=(threadpool &&)      = delete;

    //  enqueue_task
    //
    //  Runs the given function on one of the thread pool
    //  threads in First In First Out (FIFO) order
    //
    //  Arguments
    //    task - Function or functor to be called on the
    //           thread pool, takes an arbitary number of
    //           arguments and arbitary return type.
    //    args - Arguments for task, cannot be std::move'ed
    //           if such parameters must be used, use a
    //           lambda and capture via move then move
    //           the lambda.
    //
    //  Result
    //    Signals when the task has completed with either
    //    success or an exception. Also results in an
    //    exception if the thread pool is destroyed before
    //    execution has begun.
    template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
    auto enqueue_task(Func&& task, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(task(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
    {
        //  Return type of the functor, can be void via
        //  specilisation of task_package_impl
        using R = decltype(task(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        auto promise = std::promise<R>{ };
        auto future = promise.get_future();
        auto bound_task = std::bind(std::forward<Func>(task), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        // ensures no memory leak if push throws (it shouldn't but to be safe)
        auto package_ptr = std::make_unique<task_package_impl<R, decltype(bound_task)>>(std::move(bound_task), std::move(promise));

        tasks.push(static_cast<task_package *>(package_ptr.get()));

        // no longer in danger, can revoke ownership so
        // tasks is not left with dangling reference
        package_ptr.release();

#ifndef USE_YIELD
        wakeup_signal.notify_one();
#endif

        return future;
    };

private:
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::atomic<bool> shutdown_flag;

    boost::lockfree::queue<task_package *> tasks;

#ifndef USE_YIELD
    std::condition_variable wakeup_signal;
    std::mutex wakeup_mutex;
#endif

    bool pop_task(std::unique_ptr<task_package> & out);
};

#endif
```

#### threadpool.cpp

```
#include "threadpool.hpp"

#include <exception>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
constexpr T zero(T)
{
    return 0;
}

threadpool::threadpool()
    : threadpool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
{ };

threadpool::threadpool(size_t concurrency)
    : threadpool(concurrency, 128)
{ };

threadpool::threadpool(size_t concurrency, size_t queue_size)
    : tasks(queue_size)
    , shutdown_flag(false)
    , threads()
#ifndef USE_YIELD
    , wakeup_signal()
    , wakeup_mutex()
#endif
{
    // This is more efficient than creating the 'threads' vector with
    // size constructor and populating with std::generate since
    // std::thread objects will be constructed only to be replaced
    threads.reserve(concurrency);

    for (auto a = zero(concurrency); a < concurrency; ++a)
    {
        // emplace_back so thread is constructed in place
        threads.emplace_back([this]()
            {
                // checks whether parent threadpool is being destroyed,
                // if it is, stop running.
                while (!shutdown_flag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
                {
                    auto current_task_package = std::unique_ptr<task_package>{nullptr};

                    // use pop_task so we only ever have one reference to the
                    // task_package
                    if (pop_task(current_task_package))
                    {
                        current_task_package->run_task();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // rather than spinning, give up thread time to other things
#ifdef USE_YIELD
                        std::this_thread::yield();
#else
                        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(wakeup_mutex);

                        wakeup_signal.wait(lock, [this](){ return !tasks.empty() || shutdown_flag; });
#endif
                    }
                }
            });
    }
};

threadpool::~threadpool()
{
    // signal that threads should not perform any new work
    shutdown_flag.store(true);

#ifndef USE_YIELD
    wakeup_signal.notify_all();
#endif

    // wait for work to complete then destroy thread
    for (auto && thread : threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }

    auto current_task_package = std::unique_ptr<task_package>{nullptr};

    // signal to each uncomplete task that it will not complete due to
    // threadpool destruction
    while (pop_task(current_task_package))
    {
        auto except = std::runtime_error("Could not perform task before threadpool destruction");
        current_task_package->set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(except));
    }
};

bool threadpool::pop_task(std::unique_ptr<task_package> & out)
{
    task_package * temp_ptr = nullptr;

    if (tasks.pop(temp_ptr))
    {
        out.reset(temp_ptr);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### task_package.hpp

```
#ifndef TASK_PACKAGE_HPP
#define TASK_PACKAGE_HPP

#include <future>

struct task_package
{
    virtual ~task_package() { };

    void run_task() noexcept
    {
        try
        {
            run();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            set_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
    }

    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual void set_exception(std::exception_ptr except_ptr) = 0;
};

template<typename R, typename Func>
struct task_package_impl : public task_package
{
    task_package_impl(Func&& func, std::promise<R>&& promise)
        : promise(std::forward<std::promise<R>>(promise))
        , func(std::forward<Func>(func))
    { };

    virtual void run()
    {
        promise.set_value(func());
    }

    virtual void set_exception(std::exception_ptr except_ptr)
    {
        promise.set_exception(except_ptr);
    }

    std::promise<R> promise;
    Func func;
};

template<typename Func>
struct task_package_impl<void, Func> : public task_package
{
    task_package_impl(Func&& func, std::promise<void>&& promise)
        : promise(std::forward<std::promise<void>>(promise))
        , func(std::forward<Func>(func))
    { };

    virtual void run()
    {
        func();
        promise.set_value();
    }

    virtual void set_exception(std::exception_ptr except_ptr)
    {
        promise.set_exception(except_ptr);
    }

    std::promise<void> promise;
    Func func;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why do you use a `static_cast` here? `static_cast<task_package *>(package_ptr.get())`

Comment: If performance is important, you might be able to move arguments from the task by using a tuple and tuple expansion via the indices trick (store them alongside the original `Func` inside `task_package_impl`).

Answer (score 6):

You give 3 `threadpool` constructors:

```
threadpool::threadpool()
    : threadpool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
{ };

threadpool::threadpool(size_t concurrency)
    : threadpool(concurrency, 128)
{ };

threadpool::threadpool(size_t concurrency, size_t queue_size)
```

You could use one `threadpool` constructor with default arguments:

```
threadpool::threadpool(
        size_t concurrency=std::thread::hardware_concurrency()
      , size_t queue_size=128
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would make the overriding behaviour explicit in `task_package_impl` by adding the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to `run` and `set_exception`:

```
virtual void run() override
{
    promise.set_value(func());
}

virtual void set_exception(std::exception_ptr except_ptr) override
{
    promise.set_exception(except_ptr);
}
```

That way, if you ever intend to change the signature of `run` or `set_exception` in the base class (breaking changes in an interface are hardly a good idea, but they sometimes happen) and forget to change one of the derived classes, you will get a compilation error stating that `run` and/or `set_exception` are not overriding anything but merely hiding the base class function name.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about the `override` and `final` keywords from C++11. I think using `final` makes more sense as deriving from `task_package_impl` wouldn't have much use and still has the benefits of using `override`.

Comment: @TomMyles You can use `final` and it could actually help the compiler to devirtualize the calls. However, marking a class `final` is not really a good idea since many libraries derive from user-defined classes to use the empty base class optimization :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason for your compilation error is neither a bug in your code nor a compiler error - it's just a consequence of the current standard. 
It occurs, because the compiler would like to pass a copy the result of `std::move` as an input parameter to the given func, instead of taking it as a reference. As far as I remember this is the exact reason why the 'Lambda capture expressions' have been improved with the C++14 standard - so you could pass a unique_ptr, which couldn't be passed by value otherwise.